# Center image position absolute with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I tried to recreate everything as good as possible. CSS:

```
.container-fluid-max {
  max-width: 1440px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
.bg-img{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height:300px;
  border: 3px 0 solid $b-black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.bg-img img{
  max-height:450px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19984/

My problem: I am trying to get the image to be centered. Since in my project, the img is always a different/random one, I cannot really tell what height/width it does have. Just saying I dont want it to be higher than 450px.

And it's okay that it's entering the div above. That's something I want to achieve.

Comment: can you do it with flexbox? does this work https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19985/

Comment: ' position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;'

Comment: you have defined col-xs-12 and it takes up the whole screen so you may wanna try col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 or col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 to get the element centered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this Code:

```
.bg-img img{
  max-height:450px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
 left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto
}
```

Comment: One other thing I forgot to mention. If I resize to a smaller width ( by resizing browser) I'll get a scroll button on the bottom to th right and left. How do I avoid that? Any idea?

Comment: I don't get scroll bar on width:320px on FF and Chrome  browser ... In jsfiddle always show scroll bar. which browser you use ?